# Device RF input calibration setup

Tags: rf, radio, calibration, signal-generator

A device requires RF input calibration. The input signal specification is: CW, 60MHz, 0.0 dBm.
The user manual recommends setup **1** (fig below).

Provided that the Signal Generator **is capable** of outputting the specified signal, what would be the advantage of using setup **1** instead of **2**?

[image]

**Edit #1 Calibration**

The calibration rational is to insert a known signal into the device (inputPOW), read the input level (readPOW) and evaluate an offset as follows:

`inputPOW == readPOW + offset.`

Comment: It depends entirely on the device and what calibration actually means. The devil is in the detail.

Comment: @pbn:  Can the device also transmit?

Comment: pbn - Hi, Can you please tell us the actual device being calibrated, and link to its manual which specifies "setup 1" in your question, so that readers can see more context? Thanks.

Comment: also, what are signal "cleanliness" properties of your signal generator and of your amplifier, and attenuators? My best guess when I see something doing 30 dB gain and 20 dB attenuation in total is that this is actually about measuring unmatched devices, and as the others said, the devil is in the details, so we'll need way more of these tasty, juicy, fresh details.

Comment: @JRE No TX. RX only.

Comment: @SamGibson Unfortunately the manual is under NDA. There is nothing mentioning why the att pair / amp are required though. It just states that the input signal should be generate by "setup 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually they insert RF attenuators in the signal chain to avoid issues with reflected signal from the DUT. In the second case the generator outputs 0dBm straights to the device, in the first one it only needs -10dBm (and maybe with better signal quality) with the attenuators to isolate the stages.

Other than that if it's only to evaluate signal strength I don't see advantages in the first setup other than better reflection protection.